# Fencing backyard on the lower side of a retaining wall

Tags: fence, retaining-wall, backyard, pet-proofing

Trying to fence my backyard, so that the dog has some room to play and burn some energy, as well as joining us outside during gatherings.

My backyard sits on the low side of a retaining wall, which slopes down from approximately 8 ft tall down to 4 ft tall. My original fence outline is shown in blue on the drawing below; pretty much was gonna use the wall as a side of the fence. However, last week I found out that my dog can jump up the portion of the wall that is only 4ft tall.

Putting fence against the whole wall would add about 100 ft of fence, which wouldn't be cheap. Additionally it would cause a nightmare, if my neighbor ever needed to repair the wall. Thought about only fencing the 4 ft tall portion, but think that would look kind of weird...

Any ideas on what to do here, so that I can keep the dog in the yard without sacrificing yard space or adding 100 ft of fencing?

Thanks,

[image]

Comment: put a 2' fence on top of the 4' wall and extend it to the 6' high part of the wall .... keep the top of the fence straight across ..... basically, raise the height of the wall to 6' all the way across

Answer (score 1):

Add some planter boxes or some other pleasant looking obstruction to the 4 foot section. [image][image] if you are not interested in planter boxes you could do something like a gas pipe railing [image] I'm a gas fitter and I love the look of this stuff. But it may be a little costly if you want dense coverage like in the photo.

Answer (score 0):

I would get a wireless dog fence kit and start with the standard collar. I have had great success with these and have kept hunting dogs on the property. In one case I did have to get the "atomic collar"  but with these simple units a loop in an area gives anything from warning beep to a pulse that makes them think twice about taking another step ( I did try this on myself and as an electrian I have gotten a few Zaps, this one kinda hurt but was a short pulse) you can also make areas they can go through by twisting the wires. I think these units are great and would be cheaper and not change the look .

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't need fencing on the full length of the red side.  You could fence a little bit inside the retaining wall for the segment where the retaining wall is shorter.

A little jog would be needed at one end (approximately the midpoint of that side of the rectangle).